Google Workspace環境において、Google Apps Scriptの「アクセスするユーザー」に「全員（匿名ユーザーを含む）」の選択肢を表示させる手順
Google Workspaceを私が勤務している会社で利用しており、社内外のサーバ上で動作するタスク（スクリプト）の実行結果をスプレッドシートに集約、その後シートの内容をGmailで送信したいと考えています。
これらをGASを利用して実現したいと考えているのですが、その為に「Googleアカウントを保有しないユーザー/サーバ」からもGASへアクセスする必要があります。
過去Google Workspace上でGASのAPI公開を行うに際し、「アクセスするユーザー」の選択肢に「全員（匿名ユーザーを含む）」の選択肢があったと記憶しているのですが、現在その選択肢が見つかりませんため、その手順を質問する次第です。
（現在は「自分のみ」「（組織）内の全員」の2択のみ表示されています）
セキュリティ上の理由から、明示的に「全員（匿名ユーザーを含む）」のアクセスを許可する操作が必要なのでは（管理上のポリシー設定などで選択肢を表示して利用できるようにする方法があるのでは）？と想像しておりますが、具体的にどの部分を操作すれば良いのかが分かりませんでした。
お手数ですが、上記手順に付きまして、ご教示頂けますと幸いです。
